# Can god run and monitor processes for multiple environments on the same machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, god

I have a staging and development environment of a rails app on the same machine. Both us god to run and monitor a few processes.

I've set up a god service that starts/stops/restarts the god process. It starts the process by running the following command:

```
/path/to/god -P /var/run/god.pid -c /opt/god/master.conf
```

And the master.conf:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = "staging"
rails_root = ENV['RAILS_ROOT'] = "/path/to/staging/root"

load "#{rails_root}/config/god/process_one.god.rb"
load "#{rails_root}/config/god/process_two.god.rb"
```

I can run this successfully for one environment or the other but not both at the same time. How do I run it for both environments simultaneously?